# how to extract row numbering from a list and record it in a new column

Tags: string, split

I have a pandas data frame which looks like this:
data = [['page 1 of 10', '1.1 this is first line of text with a value
2.3. 1.2 this is second line. 1.3 this is third line with a float value
2.9.'],['page 2 of 10', '2.1.2
this is fourth line with a float value 1.3. 2.1.2.1 this is fifth line
of df 2.9.6. 2.1.2.2 this is sixth line.'],['page 3 of 10', '2.1.3 this
is seventh line.2.1.3.1 this is eigth line. 2.1.3.2 this is ninth
line.']]

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Page_No', 'text'])
df
```

i want to extract the numbers having a variable pattern 1.1,2.1.2,2.1.3.1 and so on, it starts before every row, all i need is to record these numbers in a new column and remove the existing text column. also the rows with this sequence numbers should get appended in a new row in the same text column.

so far i have tried multiple approaches, but they are not giving me right results, one is

```
df['text'] = df['text'].str.split('(\d+.\d+.?\d*.?\d*)\s')
df = df[~df['text'].str.contains(r'(\d+.\d+.?\d*.?\d*)')]
df = df[df['text'] != '']
df
```

The problem is the sequence numbering, it varies at every line and sometimes has 4 to 5 digits.
all I want is to get a new df with columns 'Page No', 'text', 'row no' and the text starting with every sequence numbering should be appended in a new row with the sequence no. in a row no column.

Answer (score 0):

You might use a pattern with 2 named capture groups and [extractall](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html), where group `row_no` and group `text` are returned in a new dataframe with those column names for every line in the "text" column.

Then merge the the dataframe with column `Page_No`

```
(?P<row_no>\d+(?:\.\d+)+)\s+(?P<text>.*?)(?=\d+(?:\.\d+)+(?!\S)|$)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?P<row_no>` Named group `row_no`

  - `\d+(?:\.\d+)+` Match 1+ digits, and repeat 1+ times `.` and 1+ digits
- `)` Close the group
- `\s+` Match 1+ whitespace chars
- `(?P<text>.*?)` Named group `text`, match any character except a newline, as few as possible
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert to the right

  - `\d+(?:\.\d+)+(?!\S)` Match 1+ digits, and repeat 1+ times `.` and 1+ digits asserting a whitespace boundary to the right
  - `|` Or
  - `$` Assert the end of the string
- `)` Close the lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NH3t7u/1)

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['page 1 of 10', '1.1 this is first line of text 23/1. 1.2 this is second line. 1.3 this is     third line.'],
        ['page 2 of 10',
         '2.1.2 this is fourth line. 2.1.2.1 this is fifth line of df 45.23. 2.1.2.2 this is sixth line.'],
        ['page 3 of 10', '2.1.3 this is seventh line. 2.1.3.1 this is eigth line. 2.1.3.2 this is ninth line.']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Page_No', 'text'])

pattern = r"(?P<row_no>\d+(?:\.\d+)+)\s+(?P<text>.*?)(?=\d+(?:\.\d+)+(?!\S)|$)"

# Get new dataframe with 2 columns
new_columns_from_regex = df['text'].str.extractall(pattern)

# Remove the level 1 index from the dataframe because we used extractall
new_columns_from_regex.reset_index(level=1, drop=True, inplace=True)

# Merge the dataframes using the left index from 'Page_No' with the right index from 'new_columns_from_regex'
result = df[['Page_No']].merge(new_columns_from_regex, left_index=True, right_index=True)
result.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

print(result)
```

Output

```
        Page_No   row_no                               text
0  page 1 of 10      1.1  this is first line of text 23/1. 
1  page 1 of 10      1.2              this is second line. 
2  page 1 of 10      1.3            this is     third line.
3  page 2 of 10    2.1.2              this is fourth line. 
4  page 2 of 10  2.1.2.1   this is fifth line of df 45.23. 
5  page 2 of 10  2.1.2.2                this is sixth line.
6  page 3 of 10    2.1.3             this is seventh line. 
7  page 3 of 10  2.1.3.1               this is eigth line. 
8  page 3 of 10  2.1.3.2                this is ninth line.
```

Comment: Using regex pattern for row_no is also extracting the float values available in my actual text column (of course the data shared above is only for sample purpose) and in some rows all row nos. are not getting extracted. i tried with different regex patterns as well but still not getting the expected results.

Comment: @SatishKumar Then you should add the real data instead and update the question with the expected results. Is this the format that you want?

Comment: due to data security concerns i cannot share the data. the format is correct, the data i am trying to clean is in paragraph form and it contains float values written randomly. data format is not symmetrical.

Comment: @SatishKumar So the Output in my answer has the desired format? What do you mean by `data format is not symmetrical.` ? Can you give an example of float values that you have that are not extracted and should have been? For example, what should be extracted here? `this is fifth line of df 45.23. test 12.34 test 2.1.2.2`? Can you create a fictional dataframe where you can specify the expected outcome?

Comment: i have edited my question and added some float values in text column. in your example the row is starting as '2.1.2.2 this is fifth line of df 45.23. test 12.34.' where i want to extract 2.1.2.2 as row no. and rest as a text.